# Floating point arithmetic operations when row reducing matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

A numerical note in my linear algebra text states the following: "In general, the forward phase of row reduction takes much longer than the backward phase. An algorithm for solving a system is usually measured in flops (or floating point operations). A **flop** is one arithmetic operation $(+,-,*,/)$ on two real floating point numbers. For an $n\times(n+1)$ matrix, the reduction to echelon form can take
$$
\frac{2}{3}n^3+\frac{1}{2}n^2-\frac{7}{6}n\tag{1}
$$
flops (which is approximately $2n^3/3$ flops when $n$ is moderately large--say, $n\geq 30$). In contrast, further reduction to reduced echelon form needs at most $n^2$ flops."

There is no explanation at all how the author came up with the expression in $(1)$. There is obviously a reason for that expression and the $n^2$ mentioned at the end of the quote. Can someone with knowledge of linear algebra or computer architecture, etc., explain why these expressions are the way there? It seems like the author just pulled them out of nowhere.

Answer (score 2):

The operations involved at the $k$th step of the transformation to REF, where $k=1,\ldots,n-1$, are: for each row $l=k+1,\ldots,n$,

1. compute the row multiplier: divide the entry $(k,l)$ by pivot entry $(k,k)$;
2. update the column entries $k+1,\ldots,n+1$ of the $l$th row (one multiplication and addition per entry).

(We do Item 1 and Item 2 for rows $k+1,\ldots,n$, so the numbers for both items must be multiplied by $n-k$.)
This gives the number of flops at step $k$
$$
(n-k)[1+2(n-k+1)]=2k^2-(4n+3)k+n(2n+3)
$$
and the total number of flops
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}[2k^2-(4n+3)k+n(2n+3)]=\frac{2}{3}n^3+\frac{1}{2}n^2-\frac{7}{6}n.
$$

[image]

The operations involved at the $k$th step of the transformation of REF to RREF, where $k=n,n-1,\ldots,1$, are:

1. normalize the entry $(k,k)$; this involves only one division in the entry $(k,n+1)$, since the entry $(k,k)$ becomes $1$ and all other entries of the $k$th row are zero;
2. update the entries in the rows $1,\ldots,k-1$ of the column $n+1$ (this gives $k-1$ multiplications and $k-1$ additions).

Hence, for the step $k$, we have
$$
1+2(k-1)=2k-1
$$
operations and total
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n(2k-1)=n^2.
$$

[image]

**NOTE** It is useful to recall the sums
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 = \frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1), \quad
\sum_{k=1}^n k   = \frac{1}{2}n(n+1).
$$

Comment: Can you explain what "cost" means? I'm unfamiliar with that terminology.

Comment: @snake number of operations, flops, etc. = "computational cost"

Comment: When you are doing REF and dividing the elements by the pivot, that means that you are making the pivot as $1$. ? If that is the case then the diagonal elements to the left of row $k$ should be denoted as $1$ i guess. Just for clarity

Comment: I'm not dividing diagonal elements to make them one, this is done in the next step.