# Why is the number of flops required for the backward phase in computing the reduced echelon form just $n^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

On page 20 of the book "Linear Algebra and Its Applications", it is written as follows:

> In general, the forward phase of row reduction takes much longer than the backward phase. An algorithm for solving a system is usually measured in flops(or floating point operations). A **flop** is one arithmetic operation (+, -, *, /) on two real floating point numbers. For an $n \times (n+1)$ matrix, the reduction to echelon form can take $2n^3/3 + n^2/2-7n/6$ flops (which is approximately $2n^3/3$ flops when n is moderately large-say, $n\ge30$). In contrast, further reduction to reduced echelon form needs at most $n^2$ flops.

However, I am curious why finding the RREF requires only $n^2$ flops at most. I found much helpful information in the following answer:

- [Floating point arithmetic operations when row reducing matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1161410/)

However, my remaining question is why the worst-case scenario was considered for the forward phase, but not for the backward phase.
In the forward phase, the worst-case scenario occurs for the following REF:

[image: Fig 1.]

But when finding the backward phase, it is not the worst case.

In the case of the following REF, neither the forward phase nor the backward phase is necessarily the worst case, but it is an appropriately unfavorable case:

[image: Fig 2.]

In both cases, the forward phase and backward phase each require approximately $k \times n^3$ flops, where $k$ is some constant. (I have not performed exact calculations, but since the highest order term is $n^3$, we cannot ignore it regardless of the value of $k$.)

+ In my opinion, in the second case, approximately $7/12n^3$ flops are required in the forward phase, and approximately $1/8n^3$ flops are required in the backward phase.

I am curious why such cases were not taken into consideration.

Comment: What is $n$ here, when you're looking at the rectangular case? Is it the bigger dimension or the smaller one?

Comment: The usual calculation is done for the square case. In the case $n>m$, it looks like the worst ratio between the runtime and $n^2$ occurs when and $n$ is roughly $2m$, and in this case the runtime is indeed cubic in either $n$ or $m$. (The point here is that the work to deal with one pivot is on the order of $m(n-r+1)$ and there are $r$ pivots.)

Comment: @lan I apologize for the confusion. My question was about a matrix of size n*(n+1). Could you please read the updated question and provide an answer? Thank you.

Comment: Sure, and in this case resolving each individual row operation takes 4 flops in the backward phase, so that in total the backward phase takes about $2n^2$ flops.

Comment: @lan I don't understand why only 4 flops are required for each individual row operation in the backward phase. It seems to me that each operation would take 2*(n/2+1) flops, since there are still (n/2+1) nonzero entries left.

Comment: I was referring to the first picture where the matrix is $m \times (m+1)$ and full row rank. In this case the row with the pivot only has 2 nonzero entries all the time (the bottom row had 2 already after forward elimination, the next one has 2 after the first backward sweep, etc.). This gets worse with more columns.

Comment: @lan I agree that in the first picture, each row has only 2 nonzero entries, which leads to approximately $n^2$ flops in total. However, this is not the worst-case scenario for the backward phase. The worst-case scenario occurs in the second picture, where approximately $1/8n^3$ flops are required.(This is not a negligible amount.)

My question is why the worst-case scenario was considered for the forward phase, but not for the backward phase. Or is it the case that even in the second picture, only $n^2$ flops are required?

Comment: As I said, the usual calculation that gives $n^2$ is for the square case. It doesn't work out the same in the rectangular case. (It also doesn't work out the same in the square rank-deficient case, but in this case the numbers are better, so $n^2$ is still a bound.)